# What's a good app for project management?

Tags: iphone, ipad, software-recommendation

Look, there's at least 16 million productivity apps and I've tried like 90% of them. Maybe you know of something in that last 10% that will change my life.

Here's what I'm looking for:

1. Offline functionality
2. To-do, calendar, reminders, attachments allowed
3. Cross-platform: Macbook, ipad, iphone
4. Aesthetically-pleasing interface (nothing hideous)

Here's what I don't need:

1. Multiple users
2. Collaborative functions
3. chat, IM, etc.

I've tried Things (but it's really just a fancy program for nested lists and difficult to get an overview of everything at once) and Trello (which I really like -- but it only works online).

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the money, you should give a try at [OmniFocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus.com). It might be a bit overwhelming in the beginning, you will need some time to adjust yourself to the application and find the most suitable configuration of the app. But as soon as you get in "autopilot mode" you will be quite satisfied.

If you are looking for some free alternatives I would recommend:

- Asana
- Producteev

They are not actually free, not as in beer anyway. They are freemium: you will have a set of features that are free, and another set of features that are payed, but I think that the free version do most of the job.

And there's also Trello that is simultaneously minimalistic and powerful.

Comment: What do you mean by "not as in beer anyway"?

Comment: Please check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/what-does-the-term-and-free-as-in-free-beer-mean

Comment: Can you add some details about how the tools you recommend fulfill the requirements put forth in the question?